# Xamarin IOS collectionView itemSelected works only 3 first cells

Tags: ios, xamarin, delegates, selecteditem, collectionview

I'm really blocked ! I implements a collectionView in grid list. All work! 
Now I want to use the "selectedItem" method to show another ViewController in my CollectionViewDelegate.

It works only for the 3 first cells ! But I can have 50 cells.. I suppose that it's because load only cells which appears on screen, right ?

I already tried to add a gestureRecognizer for each cell, but still not works only for 3 first cells.

Can someone help me to find why it's work for only cells and not all? And How can I do ?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: show us some code??

Comment: I can't post answer but this is my override method :     public override void ItemSelected(UICollectionView collectionView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("here");
        }